# mysqldump access denied when being used in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to create a bash script that uses `mysqldump` to create a backup of the database that is specified as parameter. However `mysqldump` fails with an `access denied` error. Using the same command directly (copying it to the shell an executing it) works without any problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... use parameters to get db name and password
# build the mysqldump command and execute it...

command="mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u ${database} -p'${pw}' --extended-insert ${database} | gzip > ${path}"
echo "$command"
echo ""
$command
```

This gives me the following output:

```
$ ./dbbak DBUSER DBNAME PASSWORD
mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u DBUSER -p'PASSWORD' --extended-insert DBNAME | gzip > /path/to/backup/backup.sql.gz

Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
-- Connecting to 127.0.0.3...
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'DBUSER'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

As said before: When I copy the echoed `mysqldump` command and execute it directly, the backup works just fine.

What is the problem here? Since the command is executed correctly when being used manually all parameters (password, username, etc.) seem to be correct. Additionally the bash script is executed with the same user account as the manual command.

**So why does the manual execution work while the bash script fails?**

**EDIT:**

As Jens pointed out in his comment, removing the quotes from the password will solve the problem. `...-p${pw}...` will work, **BUT** this will also lead to a new problem, if the password contains special characters like `$ < > ...`

I assume that the problem with the quotes is how bash parses the string. Meanwhile I found some docs that say, that it is a bad habit to store commands in variables and execute them. Instead one should execute commands directly. However the following does not work as well:

```
result=$(mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u ${database} -p'${pw}' --extended-insert ${database} | gzip > ${path})
```

When executing this with `bash -x dbbak` the output shows the problem:

```
...
++ mysqldump -alv -h127.0.0.3 --default-character-set=utf8 -u DBUSER '-p'\''DBPASS'\''' --extended-insert DBNAME
```

While I do understand why the quotes around DBPASS are added (`'DBPASS' --> \''DBPASS'\'), I do not understand why there are also quotes around`-p`.

How do I get rid of these quotes when executing the command?

Comment: remove the single quotes arround the password

Comment: This works but will lead to problems if the password contains special characters like `$`. Is there a way to use quotes **and** make the command work within the bash script?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/123928/escaping-a-password-using-mysqldump-console

Comment: Yes, the link describes perfectly why there need to be quotes around the password. So the question is the same: How to do I get quotes around the password when executing the command in the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- store the password in an environment variable `MYSQL_PWD`
- store the password in a plain-text file `.my.cnf` which you need to put into
  the home directory of the user that executes the script
- use the `mysql_config_editor` utility to store the password in an encrypted
  file

The first one is the easiest to use/implement but obviously the least secure.

I recommend to take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html) where all the possibilities are described. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Configure it by .cnf file and provide it in [`--defaults-file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=~/my_mysql.cnf db table > table.sql
```

In  `~/my_msyql.cnf`

```
[mysqldump]
user=user_name
password=my_password
host=my_host
```

This is also safe if you version this. You can save `my_mysql.cnf` differently per environment.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the single quotes around the password solved for me.